# How to query from a relationship with eager loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to query from an eager loading in laravel. I want to query a somethingfrom a relationship So I have these query :

```
$parcels = CustomerParcelDelivery::with('parcel')->where('courier_id','=',$id)
    ->orWhere('delivery_date','=',$today)
    ->select('parcel.owner_id')
    ->get() ;
```

But I get this error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parcel.owner_id')

Comment: what query you want to make on relationship?? explain little

Comment: use join method.

Comment: I want to query from the loaded relationship, but I can't do such as like parcel.owner_id.

Comment: @Fluxify If you are looking to constraint eager loading relationships, check this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 0):

Eager load the parcel's owner as well

```
$parcels = CustomerParcelDelivery::with(['parcel', 'parcel.owner'])
    ->where('parcel.courier_id','=',$id)
    ->orWhere('parcel.delivery_date','=',$today)
    ->select('parcel.owner_id')
    ->get();
```

**Edit**

You can use a `whereHas` in this case:

```
$parcels = CustomerParcelDelivery::whereHas('parcel.owner', function ($query) use ($id) {
     $query->where('owner_id', $id); 
})->orWhere('parcel.delivery_date','=',$today)
  ->get();
```

Comment: My problem would be how to query from the eager loaded relationship. For example Book::with('authors') I want to query from the authors table not from books

Answer (score 0):

Here with('parcel') is a realtion name.
Make sure parcel relation exist in "CustomerParcelDelivery" model

Reffer:https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Try using the below code:

```
$parcels = CustomerParcelDelivery::with('parcel:id,owner_id')
           ->where('courier_id','=',$id)
           ->orWhere('delivery_date','=',$today)
           ->get();
```